# How to handle different exceptions raised in different Python version

Tags: python, xml, exception

Trying to parse a malformed XML content with xml.etree.ElementTree.parse() raises different exception in Python 2.6.6 and Python 2.7.5

Python 2.6: xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError

Python 2.7: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError

I'm writing code which must run in Python 2.6 and 2.7. afaik there is no way to define code which runs only in a Python version in Python (analogous to what we could do with #ifdef  in C/C++). The only way I see to handle both exceptions is to catch a common parent exception of both (eg Exception). However, that is not ideal because other exceptions will be handled in the same catch block. Is there any other way?

Comment: From what I can tell, on python2.7, those two classes don't have a common ancestor above `Exception` which further highlights your desire to _not_ catch a common parent exception...

Comment: you can put multiple exception blocks for the same try block.

Comment: have one catch ExpatError, the other catch ParseError.

Comment: @dbliss -- I thought about suggesting that, but I don't know if `ParseError` exists on python2.6 :-).  If it does, that's a very workable solution.

Comment: @dbliss - As mgilson mentioned, ParseError does not exist on Python 2.6, so that does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but it should be workable ...

```
ParseError = xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError if sys.version < (2, 7) else xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError

try:
    ...
except ParseError:
    ...
```

You *might* need to modify what you import based on versions (or catch `ImportError` while importing the various submodules from `xml` if they don't exist on python2.6 -- I don't have that version installed, so I can't do a robust test at the moment...)

Answer (score 0):

Based on mgilson's answer:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

try:
    # python 2.7+
    # pylint: disable=no-member
    ParseError = ElementTree.ParseError
except ImportError:
    # python 2.6-
    # pylint: disable=no-member
    from xml.parsers import expat
    ParseError = expat.ExpatError

try:
    doc = ElementTree.parse(<file_path>)
except ParseError:
    <handle error here>
```

- Define ParseError in runtime depending on Python's version. Infer Python version from ImportError exception being raised or not
- Add pylint disable directives to not break Pylint validation
- For some reason, if only xml is imported, ParseError = xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError and ParseError = xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError fail; intermediate imports of etree and expat modules fix that

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution

except (ValueError):

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32625503)