# Handling different errors for different versions of python

Tags: python, json

I am having issues with catching errors by the `json` module for different versions of Python. The `json` module throws a `JSONDecodeError` for `Python 3.5.2` and `ValueError` for `Python 2.7.12`. What is the best practice for doing this?

For example, this works for `Python 2.7.12`

```
a = '{"a": [5 8]}'
try:
    d = json.loads(a)
except ValueError:
    # do something
```

and this works for `Python 3.5.2`

```
a = '{"a": [5 8]}'
try:
    d = json.loads(a)
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    # do something
```

I have seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752850/how-to-handle-different-exceptions-raised-in-different-python-version) but I want to find a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONDecodeError` is a subclass of `ValueError`:

```
>>> from json import JSONDecodeError
>>> issubclass(JSONDecodeError, ValueError)
True
```

Just stick to catching `ValueError`; it should suffice if you need to support both versions. All `JSONDecodeError` adds is a few additional fields, giving you easy access to the parsed document, and the exact position of the error.

If you need access to those attributes (provided they are present), just use `hasattr()` to test first:

```
try:
    d = json.loads(a)
except ValueError as err:
    pos = (None, None)
    if hasattr(err, lineno):
        # JSONDecodeError subclass
        pos = err.lineno, err.colno
```

Comment: Thanks. All I wanted from the error was the error message. So, this also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the `json` module in particular, which is basically [`simplejson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) packaged as `json` module and distributed with Python, you can use the latest (or at least the same) version of `simplejson`.

That way the exception in all versions of Python will be the same: `JSONDecodeError`.